# Killing a thread after closing a form?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a thread that is created when a new form-instance is opened up.
This thread should run at all times when this form is open.
After the form closes, it should die.

Problem is when I open a new instance of the same form, it uses the same thread.

The correct code I'm looking for is probably somewhere along the lines of this I'm thinking... except this is invalid:

```
t = new Task(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => totalDistance()));
```

Here's the entire code:
The method WindowsFormClosing is probably unnecessary, but I'm out of ideas.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace ITS3_Eksamen_F2014_201270810
    {
    public partial class DistanceForm : Form
    {
        Data dat;
        private string name;
        Task t;
        private bool killThread;

        public DistanceForm(Data d, string n)
        {
            dat = d;
            name = n;
            InitializeComponent();
            getDistance(name);
            nameLabel.Text = name;
            t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => totalDistance());
            killThread = false;
        }

        private void getDistance(string name)
        {
            var dList = new List<Distance>();
            dList = dat.getDistance(name);
            int i = 0;
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            foreach (Distance dist in dList)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = dist.getTid();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = dist.getAngivelse();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = dist.getLængde();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = dat.getFullName(dist.getInitialer());
                i++;
            }
        }

        private void updateInitials(string initialer, int rowNumber)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[rowNumber].Cells[3].Value = dat.getFullName(initialer);
        }

        private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int rowNumber = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

            if (!dataGridView1.Rows[rowNumber].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Equals("") 
                && !dataGridView1.Rows[rowNumber].Cells[1].Value.ToString().Equals("") 
                && !dataGridView1.Rows[rowNumber].Cells[2].Value.ToString().Equals("")
                && !dataGridView1.Rows[rowNumber].Cells[3].Value.ToString().Equals(""))
            {
                var tid = dataGridView1.Rows[rowNumber].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                var længde = dataGridView1.Rows[rowNumber].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                var angivelse = dataGridView1.Rows[rowNumber].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                var initialer = dataGridView1.Rows[rowNumber].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                dat.addDistance(name, tid, længde, angivelse, initialer);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Du skal udfylde alle felter!");
            }
            int currentRow = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            string currentRowInitialer = dataGridView1.Rows[currentRow].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            updateInitials(currentRowInitialer, currentRow);
        }

        private void buttonRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int number = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            dat.deleteDistance(name, number);
        }

        private void totalDistance()
        {
            while (killThread == false)
            {
                int totalDist = 0;
                int newDist = 0;
                var testList = dat.getDistance(name);
                foreach (Distance dist in testList)
                {
                    newDist = Convert.ToInt32(dist.getLængde().Replace(" km", ""));
                    totalDist = totalDist + newDist;
                }

                this.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                    {
                        textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(totalDist) + " km";
                    }));
            }
        }

        private void WindowsFormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            killThread = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "a new instance of the same form" -> you probably wanted to say, that you open again *the same Form instance* .

Comment: @BartoszKP is right. You should know that `Tasks` are using the `ThreadPool`, and threads on the `ThreadPool` are beeing reused. For long running tasks you should use `var task3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => totalDistance(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);` Then it will construct new threads. (there is nothing wrong with reusing threads..)

Comment: nice namespace: ITS3_Eksamen_F2014_201270810 lol

Comment: haha thanks. It's for an exam I'm completing right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use this:

```
private Thread _thread;

public DistanceForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(totalDistance));
    _thread.Start();
}

public void FormClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    killThread = true;
    _thread.Join();
}
```

Instead of using a boolean, I would advise a ManualResetEvent.

Like:

```
private Thread _thread;
private ManualResetEvent _started = new ManualResetEvent(false);
private ManualResetEvent _terminating = new ManualResetEvent(false);
private ManualResetEvent _terminated = new ManualResetEvent(false);

public void InitializeComponent()
{
    _thread = new Thread(() => totalDistance());
    _thread.Start();

    // wait until the thread is started.
    _started.WaitOne();
}

private void totalDistance()
{
    // do some initialization stuff..

    // Set started.
    _started.Set();
    while(!_terminating.WaitOne(0))
    {
        // ...
    }
    _terminated.Set();
}

public void FormClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // request for terminating.
    _terminating.Set();
    // wait until it's terminated.
    _terminated.WaitOne();
}
```

The `started` isn't relevant at this situation, but I use it normally when some instances are constructed withing the thread (like clients etc.)

***The example is without exception handling. you should add  try/finally.***

This way you have total control about jobs on the threads and the boolean check is **threadsafe**

The whole thing can be wrapped inside a new object. :)

Comment: Looks great!
I'm getting this though:
Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.
I'm using your recommended solution, not the boolean anymore.

Comment: I made an update (constructor), if it still doesn't work, use the `Loaded` event.

Comment: Added your update, can you elaborate on how to use the Loaded event? I'm not very good with events and threads.

Comment: Open the Form in designmode, press F4 to show the property editor and select events. Find the `Loaded` event.

Comment: Okaayyyy... what exactly is supposed to happen with this event? I found the Loaded event. Sorry for being stupid.

Comment: This `event` is raised when all properties are loaded/initialized. These general questions are answered by google.

Comment: Ok buddy I figured out what to do. Thanks for your help!